# Why can't Prettier find the "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss" plugin on a Remix app?

Tags: tailwind-css, prettier, remix.run

## Background

I'm trying to setup a Remix app using Tailwind CSS for styling and Prettier for styling. Recently the Tailwind team released their official classes-sorting plugin but for some reason Prettier says it "can't find it".

The error looks like the following in the Prettier output:

```sh
    ["INFO" - 1:17:09 PM] Formatting file:///home/juanzitelli/dev/human-decode/burger-reviews-hd/app/routes/dashboard/index.tsx
    ["ERROR" - 1:17:09 PM] Error resolving prettier configuration for /home/juanzitelli/dev/human-decode/burger-reviews-hd/app/routes/dashboard/index.tsx
```

My file structure (files related to the problem) looks like this:

```
    /prettier.config.js
    /tailwind.config.js
```

`/package.json`

````
    "devDependencies": {
        "@remix-run/dev": "^1.1.3",
        "@remix-run/serve": "^1.2.2",
        "@types/node": "^17.0.21",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.24",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "concurrently": "^7.0.0",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.6",
        "prettier": "^2.5.1",
        "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.1.8",
        "prisma": "^3.10.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
        "typescript": "^4.1.2"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=14",
        "yarn": "1.22.17"
      },

Prettier config 

`/prettier.config.js`

    module.exports = {
      plugins: [require('prettier-plugin-tailwindcss')],
    };


> When hovering over that "require" I get an error that says:

module "/home/juanzitelli/dev/human-decode/burger-reviews-hd/node_modules/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss/dist/index"
Could not find a declaration file for module 'prettier-plugin-tailwindcss'. '/home/juanzitelli/dev/human-decode/burger-reviews-hd/node_modules/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'prettier-plugin-tailwindcss';`ts(7016)```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this problem too before. Though I just tried adding the Tailwind Prettier plugin to a new Remix project and everything seems to be working. Here are the steps I performed:

1. [Installed Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/remix) `npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer concurrently`
2. After finishing all the steps outlined in the link above, I ran `npm install -D prettier prettier-plugin-tailwindcss`

I don't have a prettier config file in place. I'm able to run Prettier through vscode and I can confirm that the Tailwind classes are automatically sorted.

Comment: How did you run the Prettier?  The plugin  only works in my Ubuntu machine using `npx prettier --write index.html`. However, when I hit save in VScode, Prettier works but the prettier-plugin-tailwindcss doesn't sort the Tailwind classes as expected."

Comment: My problem was that I didn't have Prettier configured for .js files. I had to use `Ctrl+Shift+P` -> `Format Document` and select prettier.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem even though I had everything installed and setup correctly. It got resolved after reloading VS Code through "Command Palette (CTRL + SHIFT + P) > Reload Window". Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The main reasons that caused this issue for me were the versions of my modules, such as Node.js (I had `version 18`) and Prettier (`version 2.8.3`). Additionally, you need to include the following line in your Prettier config file (`.prettierrc` in my case): `"plugins": ["prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"]`.

After updating the versions of my packages to the latest and reloading VS Code through the 'Command Palette' (`CTRL + SHIFT + P`) > 'Reload Window', the plugin finally works!